# Python convert hanzi character

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-2.7

How do I convert between a hanzi character and it's unicode value as depicted below?

- `与` to `U+4E0E`
- `今` to `U+4ECA`
- `令` to `U+4EE4`
- `免` to `U+514D`

Appears unsupported by default:

```
>>> a = '安'

Unsupported characters in input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small 'u' in front of the quote indicates that a Unicode string is supposed to be created.

```
>>> a = u'与'
>>> a
u'\u4e0e'
```

See the the string documentation for more information: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

**Update:** 
Set the source file encoding according to the actual encoding of the file, so that the interpreter knows how to parse it.

For example, to use UTF-8 just add this string to the header of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```